# Chrome extension only works on specific websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My Chrome extension only works at 'developer.chrome.com', how can I set a wildcard so it works on all websites?

[background.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5KkZ.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: you should ad the code, not a link to an image of the code. :)

Comment: Hi, I've already sort of fixed the problem in the comments in the answer under here. This is enough, when I want to reproduce the problem I have to create a new extension because I can't share the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `matches:["<all_urls>"]`

Comment: The option 'schemes' : ['http', 'https', 'chrome'] does the extension give more permission overall but still not functional on all websites. When I open a new tab the extension is grayed out again.

Comment: this answer matches the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permission_warnings

Comment: I know it matches the docs, but it doesn't work like it should which is weird. Anyways I am using the solution above that I've found. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the content_scripts in your manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches":["*://*/*"]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've tried this but I must define a javascript or css file. Which I don't need. I have selected it anyway and it still did not solve the problem. I'll grab the solution above in the comments.